# We scraper not retrieving table

Tags: python, mechanize

I am using the following Python script to fill up the form at the following page:

```
http://www.bseindia.com/indices/IndexArchiveData.aspx?expandable=3
```

The website shows up the table by manual browser, but when I use the following python mechanize module to mimic the browser activity, I get a blank table in the response variable. Why is this so? How do I resolve this?

```
import httplib 
import urllib 
import urllib2 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import gmtime,strftime
import csv
import sys
import cookielib


# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

#list=["BSE30  ","BSE500 ","AUTO   ","BANKEX ","BSECG  ","BSECD  ","BSEFMCG", "BSEHC  ","MIDCAP ","SMLCAP ","TECK   ","METAL  ","OILGAS "]
list=["BSEFMCG"]
myfile = open('CII_Report.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

#Time
date_today=sys.argv[2]
date_then=sys.argv[1]
print date_today,date_then

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'),('Accept', '*/*')]

for item in list:
    url = 'http://www.bseindia.com/indices/IndexArchiveData.aspx?expandable=3'
    br.open(url)
    response = br.response().read()
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.set_all_readonly(False)
    br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFromDate']='14/11/3012'
    br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtToDate']='29/11/2013'
    br.form.set_value([item],name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlIndex')
    response = br.submit().read()
    result=response.strip().split('\r\n')
    print result
    a='''close_last=result[1].split(',')[4]
    close_current=result[len(result)-1].split(',')[4]
    diff=float(close_current)-float(close_last)
    diff_file="%.1f" %((diff*100.0)/float(close_last))

    wr.writerow([item])
    wr.writerow([result[len(result)-1].split(',')[0],close_current])
    wr.writerow([result[1].split(',')[0],close_last])
    wr.writerow(["CHANGE(%)",diff_file])
    wr.writerow([" "])'''

myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself.

There was an onCLick function() getting called, which was changing an elements value.

Had to include:

```
br['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hidInd']="BSE30  "
```

and it worked like a charm !